# Como quitar los separadores de miles('comas') de un inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera que al darle click al boton este me arrojara la respuesta sin el separador de miles

```js
$(".numeric").inputmask({
  groupSeparator: ",",
  alias: "integer",
  placeholder: "0",
  autoGroup: !0,
  digitsOptional: !1,
  clearMaskOnLostFocus: !1
}).click(function() {
  $(this).select();
});

function myFunction() {
  alert($("#r1").val());
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm numeric" value="0" id="r1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: ¿te refieres a la comas?¿y sólo quieres que desaparezca en el `alert` o también del `input` al escribir?

Comment: si me refiero a las comas, solo quiero que desaparezca en el alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede usar la función `replace` de `string`: [documentación replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace)

Y en vez de usar `','` usamos `/,/g` porque así en vez de un `substring` que se busca, es una expresión regular, y este caso el `g` indica `global`, es decir, todas las comas del valor que se intenta modificar.

Fíjate también que, a pesar de introducir un número en el input, su tipo es `string`como venía diciendo, porque la función `val()` devuelve un `string`.

```js
$(".numeric").inputmask({
  groupSeparator: ",",
  alias: "integer",
  placeholder: "0",
  autoGroup: !0,
  digitsOptional: !1,
  clearMaskOnLostFocus: !1
}).click(function() {
  $(this).select();
});

function myFunction() {
  let inVal = $("#r1").val().replace(/,/g, '');
  alert(inVal);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm numeric" value="0" id="r1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Gracias viejo me sirvio mucho